# several alias namespaces in if-statement

Tags: c++, namespaces

is it possible to set a namespace alias in an if-statement and use it afterwards?

I tried it with the following code:

```
 const int dim = 2;
         //default namespace
        namespace poissonProblem = poissonProblem3D;
         //trying to set the necessary namespace
        if(dim == 1){
            namespace poissonProblem = poissonProblem1D;
        }
        else if (dim == 2){
            namespace poissonProblem = poissonProblem2D;
        }
        else if (dim == 3){
            namespace poissonProblem = poissonProblem3D;
        }
```

But when I try to use a function such as `poissonProblem::eval()` afterwards, it's still the function `poissonProblem3D::eval()` which is used.

Have you any ideas why, or suggestions for other ways of implementation/work-arounds?

I don't want to implement the code for every dimension because it's almost the same despite the used namespace.

Thanks,
Justus

Comment: Is `dim` known at compile-time?

Comment: No, that can't be done. Do you know about templates?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: yes dim is known at compile-time

Comment: @jrok: Why can't it be done? Of course I know about templates but this doesn't help me in this case because the files containing the namespaces are auto-generated and are containing to many classes and functions to pass them as template parameters

Comment: `namespace` is a compile time concept. Your `if` statements execute at runtime.

Comment: @AlanStokes thanks, that's senseful, I think. Hav you any idea for a work-aorund? I'm actually quite confused because the only ways I could imagine were this one or passing the namespace as a templete parameter and unfortunately both ways are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace alias that you define is meant for telling the compiler which namespace to use when looking up for symbols at compile time.

**What's the problem ?**

So when you write

```
   if(dim == 1) {
        namespace poissonProblem = poissonProblem1D;
    }
```

you just define a namespace alias for the if-bloc.  It's forgotten as soon as you leave the block.

You should not think that the namespace alias is something dynamic that could be changed in the sequence of your program.

**Why is it so ?**

Imagine:

```
namespace poissonProblem1D { 
    class X { 
    public: 
        X(int c) {}   // constructor only with int parameter
        virtual ~X() {} // virtual destructor
    };  // only a constructor with int is allowed
}

namespace poissonProblem2D { 
    class X { 
    public: 
        X() {}   // only constructor without argument
        ~X() {}  //  non virtual destructor
    };  // only a constructor with int is allowed
}
```

Suppose now that you could redefine the namespace in the flow of execution as you desired, and that the execution of if-blocks could alter the the namespace alias.  How could the compiler then compile the statement:

```
poissonProblem::X  x(2);
```

We have two types `poissonProblem1D::X` and `poissonProblem2D::X`, but the compiler wouldn't know at compile time which one to use, which are the valid or invalid parameters and how to generate code for the destruction of the object x.

C++ has strong compile-time type checking which makes dynamic namespace alias impossible.

**Edit: How to solve it ?**

It depends on the context.  Kerek already showed a template based approach.

Another approach is to use conditional compilation.  This can prove useful for configuring the the namespace at compilation time (for example choose to use a boost or a std version of a class such as regex).

```
#define dim 2
#if dim==2
        namespace poissonProblem = poissonProblem2D;
#elif dim==1
        namespace poissonProblem = poissonProblem1D;
#elif dim==3
        namespace poissonProblem = poissonProblem3D;
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use a trait class template:

```
template <int> struct Feature;

template <> struct Feature<1> {
    static void eval() { problem1D::eval(); }
    // ... other functions
};

template <> struct Feature<2> {
    static void eval() { problem2D::eval(); }
    // ... other functions
};
```

Usage:

```
const int dim = 2;

int main() {
    Feature<dim>::eval();
}
```

Comment: could I also use the full namespace in each struct like

`template <int> struct Feature;

template <> struct Feature<1> {
    using namespace problem1D;
    // ... other functions
};

template <> struct Feature<2> {
  using namespace problem2D;
};`

because doing this for all functions would be a lot of work and the subfunctions are changing very often.

Comment: @JustusSchock: No, you can't have using directives in class definitions. Do you control the entire API? A really terrible hack would be to add a dummy tag parameter to each function and then use ADL...

Comment: no I dont control the  entire API.  The files containing the namespaces are generated automatically by a Form-language-compiler based in python-based form-language descriptions of problems